# Installing Nodejitsu

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have successfully installed NodeJitsu using NPM.  However, anytime I attempt to run it I get the following error:

```
TypeError:  Arguments to path.join must be strings.
```

It happens at line 204 in path.js

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/bower/issues/270

Comment: node -v; npm -v, platform details help

Answer (score 2):

We are working on release our toolset with node 0.10.0 support, you can use it with the last 0.8.x branch (0.8.22). We will publish a new version as soon as possible.

This issue is fixed internally but we are working on all the possible points of failure in node 0.10.0.

Stay tunned for updates!

If you need support you can join #nodejitsu on Freenode ;)